# cuda 11 fails to compile due to type_traits in standard library when using extended lambda expression

Tags: c++, cuda, type-traits, nvcc

I'm compiling a project using CUDA 11 with the feature of extended lambda expression,
I found that the following code cannot pass the compilation using NVCC (CUDA 11.8)

```cpp
// test.cu
#include <iostream>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Lam>
__global__ void map(int n, Lam func) {
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (tid < n) {
        func(tid);
    }
}
template<typename S,typename F>
__global__ void diveq(size_t len, S* src, F f) {
    size_t tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(tid >= len) return;
    src[tid] /= f;
}

template <typename T>
struct array_t
{
    T *_ptr;
    size_t _len;
    __host__ __device__ array_t(T *ptr, size_t len) : _ptr(ptr), _len(len) {}
    template <typename F, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<F>, int> = 0>
    __host__ array_t& operator/=(F f)
    {
        T *src = _ptr;
        size_t grid_size, block_size = 512;
        grid_size = (_len + block_size - 1) / block_size;
        auto ker = [=] __device__(int eid) { src[eid] /= f; };
        map<<<grid_size, block_size>>>(_len, ker);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        return (*this);
    }
};

void testMain(void)
{
    float *pfloats;
    cudaMalloc(&pfloats, sizeof(float) * 10000);
    array_t<float> farr(pfloats, 10000);
    farr /= 2.f;
    cudaFree(pfloats);
}
```

I run the command `nvcc --std=c++17 --extended-lambda --compile ./test.cu -o test.o` and it gives me error :

```
./test.cu: In member function ‘array_t<T>& array_t<T>::operator/=(F)’:
./test.cu:26:102: error: ‘__T0’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘__y0’?
   26 |         auto ker = [=] __device__(int eid) { src[eid] /= f; };
      |                                                                                                      ^   
      |                                                                                                      __y0
./test.cu: In instantiation of ‘array_t<T>& array_t<T>::operator/=(F) [with F = float; int <anonymous> = 0; T = float]’:
./test.cu:38:17:   required from here
./test.cu:26:12: error: could not convert ‘&((array_t<float>*)this)->*operator/=<<template arguments error> >’ from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘array_t<float>& (array_t<float>::*)(float)’
   26 |         auto ker = [=] __device__(int eid) { src[eid] /= f; };
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
./test.cu:26:12: error: could not convert ‘&((array_t<float>*)this)->*operator/=<<template arguments error> >’ from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘array_t<float>& (array_t<float>::*)(float)’
```

But if I substitute `std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<F>, int> = 0` with `int K = 0`, Or, if I replace the lambda expression and map function with a template `__global__` function call `diveq<<<grid_size,block_size>>>(_len, src, f)`, it passes the compilation,. Why does it happen? The error message makes no sense to me :(

Answer (score 1):

I thought it was a compiler bug, but it wasn't.
There are restrictions on the usage of extended lambda expression. According to https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#extended-lambda-restrictions Point 9:

> If the enclosing function is an instantiation of a function template or a member function template, and/or the function is a member of a class template, the template(s) must satisfy the following constraints:
>
> - The template must have at most one variadic parameter, and it must be listed last in the template parameter list.
> - **The template parameters must be named**. : )
> - The template instantiation argument types cannot involve types that are >either local to a function (except for closure types for extended lambdas), or are private or protected class members.

So the solution is adding a dummy name to the second parameter : `std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<F>, int> dummy = 0`